# Python - Show a variable with the name that string equals?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.5

Is there any way in python to show a variable with the name of the value of another variable???

```
num1 = "lol"
var = "1"
print(var.(print variable with the name of value))
```

I want the variable of `num1` to be shown if `var`'s value equals `num1`

Comment: Lol , `1 = "lol"` is a SyntaxError in python

Comment: Lol, `1` cannot be variable name...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can say `print(eval(1))` except that `1` is not a valid variable name.  Variable names cannot start with digits.  You can have `num1`, but not `1` by itself.

Comment: So would it be print(eval(num1)) then to get the variable instead of print(eval(1))

Comment: @Panchi: Yes it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from concerns about valid variable names:

```
print locals()['name_of_var']
```

Comment: @Panchi Have you changes your variable name to something valid?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use a dictionary?

```
some_dict = {'1':"lol", '2':"other string", 'another key':"another string"}
var = '1'
print some_dict[var]
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah like @StephenTG said, or a list for that matter:

```
myList["blank", "lol"]
print(myList[var])
```